# How to unpack a tar to its original directory

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, tar

I'm writing a simple archiving script in OSX and I'm trying to use tar to create an archive of a directory deep inside my filesystem.  I would love to save that tar on another drive.  At some point, I'd love to be able to unpack that tar from the second drive and have it drop right into the same parent directory where I originally archived it.  If that directory didn't exist, the tar would create that directory path to that particular folder.

So far I can create a tar that recreates the folder path from the exact place I unpacked it on Drive 2, but I can't figure out how to get it to just drop into a path that already exists.  Right now what I'm trying is to get this...

```
tar cvf Drive2/DirectoryToArchive.tar Drive1/Folder1/ParentFolder/DirectoryToArchive
```

Followed by this...

```
tar xvf Drive2/DirectoryToArchive.tar
```

To yield me an unpacked, reinstated DirectoryToArchive in

```
Drive1/Folder1/ParentFolder/
```

I want to be able to give this script to people who don't know terminal and have it work for them without having to place the tar in a specific directory.  Is that something tar can do?

Comment: Try `tar cPvf someTarBall.tar /path/starting/with-a-slash`

Comment: Note that with Mark's solution, you will need to specify `-P` when the tarball is extracted as well.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkSetchell and @WilliamPursell!  That works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Let me show an example of compressing and extracting to the original dir and files using tar.

On host c1669-node2:

```sh
% tar -zcvf jdk64.gz /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/
% pwd
/root
% ls -1 | grep -Ei jdk
jdk64.gz
```

On host kyan-hdp01:

```sh
% scp root@c1669-node2:/root/jdk64.gz /tmp/
% tar -xzvf /tmp/jdk64.gz -C /
% ls -lh /usr/jdk64/ | head -n 5
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 8 10 143 255 Sep 23  2016 jdk1.8.0_112
```

So I think if you compress the file with a absolute path then extract it use the `-C /` to specify dir it would be exactly as the same path as the orinal dir.